# How do I access a HTLM element that was load with a JQuery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I access an element inside the **header.html** file, loaded in the javascript code, using **`document.getElementById("element")`** inside the **index.js**? There is another way of accessing it from the **index.js** file?

**index.html file**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
    <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $("#header").load("header.html");
            $("#footer").load("footer.html");
        });
    </script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.9.0/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/index.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript" defer></script>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: You wouldn't put a `#` symbol in your ID selector when using `getElementById`, so simply removing it could work. But since you're using jQuery anyway, you could access the elements like `$('#header .element')`, for example, if an element being loaded into the header had the class of `element`.

Comment: Not sure if you want to use jQuery or JavaScript. if you want to use jQuery it's as follows: `$('#someelement').load('header.html #header')`.

Comment: I am trying to get a reference of the object to use it with an **onclick**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds to me like you would need to wait until `$("#header").load("header.html");` is done before trying to do anything with the loaded contents. Perhaps `$("#header").load("header.html", onHeaderLoaded);` might work (assuming you have a function named `onHeaderLoaded` defined somewhere, possibly even in `index.js`)

See [jQuery .load()](https://api.jquery.com/load/) for details on using the complete function.

Comment: Thank you! It worked! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this using Jquery:

```
$.get('header.html', null, function(content){
   alert($(content).find('#element'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to load your header.html into an existing element in your page, and then you can do using JQuery:

```
$( "#existing-element" ).on( "click", "element-from-header-file", function() {
    //do stuff
});
```

Or you can use body instead, if you don't want to/can not load your header into an existing element:

```
$( "body" ).on( "click", "element-from-header-file", function() {
    //do stuff
});
```

You may want to read [this](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).